# Figuring out aduisition dates of images from file names using Earthexplorer

Tags: metadata, date, earth-explorer

I have multiple eMODIS NDVI V6 earthexplorer images that someone else downloaded some time ago. Given my internet and time limitations, I want to use such images in a forthcoming project. However, I only have the .tif files with the original names and, after struggling for a while, I have been unable to figure out how to get the acquisition dates for a given image.
When you first access the earthexplorer website, they provide a link name that clearly states the acquisition dates:

[image]

That is, in the example, it is clear that the image dates are from EMAFA**20210826**202109056 to EMAFA20210826**20210905**6.
However, that same link downloads a .zip file named
AF_eMAH_NDVI.2021.238-248.QKM.COMPRES.006.2021251160341.zip, whose acquisition date is no longer clear (at least for me), further than the year. Even worst, these .zip contain several files, and my student only kept the NDVI .tif ones (in the previous example):

[image]

Again, in this case, the only date-related information provided in the file name is the year (2021).
I only need to know the year and the month of the images, so, do you any clue regarding how to get such information and share it with me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date in your example is a day of year (or julian day). The 2021.238-248  means the 238th to the 248th day of 2021 and can be converted to dd/mm/yyyy using a number of online lookups or converters.

E.g http://www.easysurf.cc/wdate5.htm or https://people.biology.ucsd.edu/patrick/julian_cal.html

So 2021.238 == 26/08/2021 and 2021.248 == 05/09/2021